# E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.posts index: text_1 dup key: { text: null }

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to get an acsses to add new post to my database in mongoDB.
I've written code for module.

```java
    const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title:{
          type:String,
          require: true,
          unique: true,
      },
      description: {
          type: String,
          require: true,
          unique: true,
      },
      tags:{
          type: Array,
          default:[],
      },
      viewsCount: {
          type:Number,
          default: 0,
      },
      user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          require:true,
      },
       imageUrl:String, 
    }, {
       timestamps: true, 
    });
```

This function is for checking new creating post before publication.

```java
    export default (req, res, next) => {
        const token = (req.headers.authorization || '').replace(/Bearer\s?/,'');

    if (token) {
         try {
             const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123'); 
             req.userId = decoded._id; 
             next(); 
         } catch(e) {
             return res.status(403).json({
                 message:"нет доступа",
             })
         }

     } else {
         return res.status(403).json({
             message:"нет доступа",
         })
     }
    }
```

This functon is for creating post after validation.

```java
    export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const doc = new PostModel({
                title: req.body.title,
                description: req.body.description,
                tags: req.body.tags,
                imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
                userId: req.userId,
            });

            const post = await doc.save();
            res.json(post);

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json({
                message: ' не удалось создать пост'
            })
        }
    }
```

Finally code.

```java
    app.post('/posts',checkAuth, postCreateValidation, createPost);
```

In the beginnig I added the first post ease wwhithout mistakes.

```java
    {
      "title": "#3sd",
      "description": "xzsadasdaasdcz ",
      "tags": ["sasdsd", "asdsds", "dssdsd"],
      "imageURL": "https://kartinkof.club/uploads/posts/2022-05/1653102447_23-kartinkof-cl26.jpg"
    }
```

But when I try to add second post i've seen this mistakes in console.

```java
    MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.posts index: text_1 
    dup key: { text: null }
```

I can't understand, what's the text:null?

Answer (score 0):

At the first I've created post with body:

```
    {
      "title": "",
      "text": "",
      "tags": ["sad", "asjkldss", ""],
      "imageURL": ""

    }
```

`title` and `text` are unique and their index is saved in mongoDB.
Then, I've changed the body:

```
    {
      "title": "",
      "description": "",
      "tags": ["sad", "asjkldss", ""],
      "imageURL": ""

    }
```

And I needed to delete unique saved indexes and it's working.
I've deleted in mongoDB compass.